# Https Redirect block

Tags: php, redirect, https, block

I have a php script that redirects to an external https page, but unfortunately firefox (and maybe other browser, didn't try yet) block https redirects with a really "scary" message for the most inexperienced users.

Is there a way to bypass this issue without asking the user to handle their browser preferences?

For the redirect I'm using a simple `header ("Location: $url");`

Thank you

Comment: What's the web server? Can you use a .htaccess ?

Comment: How about an iframe? Could you display the HTTPS page 'inside' yours?

Comment: yes, I have .htaccess, the server is apache 2.0 a for the inframe it wouldn`t be convenient for my purpose, but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

If a user has their Firefox preferences set to show a warning when a redirect happens, you can't get around it.

You can avoid this by showing an interstitial page where users can manually click on a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```